# How do i import a xls file data into sqlite3

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, data-import

I am having data in a excel sheet, It is large data i want to import all the data in excel to sqlite3, I am using this data for iPhone.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Export the Excel file to CSV format
2. Use the .import command:

   ```
   .separator ","
   .import excel_export.csv your_table
   ```

Reference:

- [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)
- [Importing Files](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)